# Headlines proclaim: "Read about this man's amazing life!"

Tags: lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle, story

A man wakes up and goes along to get drunk. He talks foolishly, but works hard and gets paid, but passes the money on to a dependent.  Every evening he comes home.  As he grows old, he is lonely and dreams about different times.

The man lives in Edinburgh, Scotland.  One day, he decides to walk due east, stopping at a city, then directly southwest, stopping at another city.

**What city does he end up in?**

Clarification:

> For walking, assume he walks straight-line distances ignoring features that might make it technically impassible, i.e. bodies of water, etc

Comment: Hmm. Some sort of board game?

Comment: No, I think I remember this one, it might be a song or book.

Comment: Not sure the stated answer really works: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-QbUB3MO2fTg/U34S7PC8lmI/AAAAAAAAAwA/V2W8X3lUYC4/s1600/proclaimers.png

Comment: @A E - it's not a direct line, because he changes direction after 500 miles.  See: http://i.imgur.com/ZSOkEZD.png, each leg is just a tad over 500mi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it's based on:

> the song by the Proclaimers, who walked 500 miles and then walked 500 more. (Havering = talking foolishly, headline *proclaims*, drunk, work hard, give away money etc.)
>
> Going east 500 miles and then south west 500 miles lands you in London, I'd say...

Comment: Nicely done! This is correct

Comment: I wasn't sure what the city between the two was.  But I guess it needs a bit of license given the other restrictions.  Nice puzzle!

Comment: I was going for the city of Horsens, in Denmark - less well-known, but 500 mi directly due east of Edinburgh, and I wanted to start in Edinburgh as a clue (that's where the band is from)

Comment: Also kudos to @Kingrames, who first had the song idea...

Comment: I claim Victory!